# Angular 12 custom index configuration aspx scripts not working

Tags: php, asp.net, angular, angular12

I'm using a custom index configuration in angular.json, and instead of index.html file, I'm working with index.aspx.

In this file, I have some asp scripts that get some data from the server.

it works ok until Angular 12, and when I've upgraded to Angular 12, the angular compiler escapes the asp tags.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to wrap the asp tags with HTML comment

`<!-- <% [some asp script] %> -->`